# EasyGUI How to define input in if loop in python 2.7.11

Tags: python-2.7, if-statement, easygui

I was wondering how I could use input from a choicebox into a if loop. All help appreciated!
e.g:

```
title = 'Title'
msg = 'Message'
choices = ['Choice1', 'Choice2']
decided = choicebox(title, msg, choices)

if decided == 'Choice1':
    print'Choice 1 is a choice that you have selected.'
```

Answer (score 0):

### ANSWER: It's that code! Sorry! I was typing off memory and I did not check what I put in, and by conisidence, it works!